# How to prove a region remains connected if one point is excluded?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm in trouble to prove this:

> Let $G$ be a region such that $a \in G$. Prove that $G \backslash \{a\}$ is a
>   region.

MY ATTEMPT: $G \backslash \{a\}$ is open as it is nothing but $G \cap \{a\}^c$; intersection of two open sets. I have tried to prove connectedness from contradiction. We assume it is not connected, i.e. there exists two open sets $U$ and $V $ such that $G$ \ {$a$} $=$ $U \cup V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Now I claim that there exists an open ball, say $B(a,r)$, contained in either $U \cup \{a\}$ or in $V \cup \{a\}$. If my claim is true then $G =U_1\cup V_1$, with $U_1 = U \cup \{a\}$ or $U_1 =U$. Similarly I take $V_1 = V\cup \{a\}$ or $V$. If $B(a,r)$ is contained in $V \cup \{a\}$ i rename it $V_1$ and choose $U_1 = U$ and similarly if $B(a,r) \subset U \cup \{p\}$ , I rename it $U_1$ and take $V_1 =V$.

Clearly $U_1 \cap V_1 = \emptyset$, which draws a contradiction that $G$ is not connected i.e. not a region.

My problem is  HOW TO PROVE MY CLAIM that there exists such an open ball $B(a,r) \subset U \cup \{a\}$. I have thought about an intuitive approch; as $G$ is open there exists an open ball $B(a,r') \subset G =U\cup V \cup \{a\}$. If $B(a,r') \subset$ one of $U \cup \{a\}$ or $V \cup \{a\}$ , I take $r' = r$ and my claim is proved and I'm happy. If that open ball is not contained in any of those two I assume that there is no radius $r$ for which an open ball containing $a$ is a subset  of $U \cup \{a\}$, so my intution says that if I repeatedly decrease the radius after a certain amount of time that open ball will be contained in $G \backslash U = V  \backslash \{a\}$. So again my claim is proved.

But I think that I need to be more rigorous, which I'm not doing here. How can I do it? Or is my intution is wrong? Thanks for reading.

Comment: I assume by *region* you mean an open connected set in an euclidean space (therefore it is path-connected). Maybe you can argue directly that surrounding $a$ you can take an open ball $B(a,r)$ inside the region, which remains connected after substracting $a$ (this is easy to show). Since this balls lies in the interior of the region, you could build a path from any point inside the ball to the outside.

Comment: @Javi,thanks I have just made my problem too complicated . It  was an easy math  if you apply path connectedness.

Comment: The proposition is false if the region is one dimensional.  Otherwise removing countably points should leave the region connected.

Comment: Your post had several Mathjax issues and some issues with grammar, I edited it in order to address them. To be more specific, in the future try to avoid separating equations ($A=B$ is *dollarsign*A=B*dollarsign*, not *dollarsign*A*dollarsign* *dollarsign* = *dollarsign* *dollarsign*B*dollarsign*), for example. For a more thorough reference, you can see [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

A region is an open and connected subset of $\mathbb C$.

Clearly, $\mathbb C\setminus \{a\}$ is open since it is the complement of the single point $\{a\}$ and single points are closed in Hausdorff spaces.

Note that, removing one point from the plane doesn't make the plane disconnected. In fact it is still path-connected. Say, $a,b$ and $c$ lie on the same line. Then you can go  from $b$ to $c$ by drawing a straight line from $b$ to $d$ and a line from $d$ to $c$ where $d$ is any point in the plane different than $a$.

As a matter of fact, removing a countable set from the plane doesn't effect path-connectedness.